# ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails app that's built largely on Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial. I'm getting an error in Logentries that I can't quite track down.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)):
31: <div class="inner">
32: <h1 id="fadeThis" style="display: none;">The Lake County Bar Association</h1>
33:
heroku router - - at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.example.org request_id="REMOVED" fwd="xx.xx.xx.xx" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=1669 protocol=http
34: <% if logged_in? %>
35: <br>
36: <h2 class="margin-top-0 wow fadeIn" id="welcomeText"> Welcome back, <%= current_user.first_name %>! </h2>
37: <% else %>
app/models/user.rb:46:in `authenticated?'
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:11:in `current_user'
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:21:in `logged_in?'
app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb:34:in `_app_views_static_pages_home_html_erb__118074299580396133_69921140988760'
```

Here are the authenticated? methods in user.rb:

```
def authenticated?(remember_token)
  return false if remember_digest.nil?
  BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
end
# Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
def authenticated?(attribute, token)
  digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
  return false if digest.nil?
  BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
end
```

And the current_user and logged_in? methods from the sessions_helper.rb:

```
def current_user
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end 
end

def logged_in?
  !current_user.nil?
end
```

And the relevant section from home.html.erb:

```
  <% if logged_in? %>
  <br>
  <h2 class="margin-top-0 wow fadeIn" id="welcomeText"> Welcome back, <%= current_user.first_name %>! </h2>
  <% else %>
  <h3> <span class="element"> <br></span></h3>
  <hr>
  <br>
```

Comment: Seems like you have 2 `def authenticated?` methods in your **User** model, with the second one(having 2 arguments) overriding the first(having only 1 argument)

Comment: Shouldn't they both be there? The signature of each method is slightly different.

Comment: This article is good for making you understand what is happening: https://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2015/04/08/method-overloading-in-ruby/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I see now. The error implies that only one argument is being sent and it was expecting to receive 2, right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: So then it must be an issue with where authenticated is being called?

Comment: I see this code calling **authenticated?**: `user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])`, which expects 2 args

Answer (score 1):

Ruby doesn't really supports method overloading. From this [*doc*](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_overloading_methods.html)

> You want to create two different versions of a method with the same
>   name: two methods that differ in the arguments they take. However, a
>   Ruby class can have only one method with a given name (if you define a
>   method with the same name twice, the latter method definition prevails

So in your case only `authenticated?(attribute, token)` gets called

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, **Ruby does not support method overloading based on parameters**. To be able to do what you want to do, you can use arguments, keyword arguments or options hash.

My preference is for the keyword arguments since I've seen that in Python a lot and really like how clear it is. Your preference or the project preference may be different.

## method overloading via argument count checking

```
def authenticated?(*args)
  case args.count
  when 1
    remember_token = args[0]
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  when 2
    attribute, token = args
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end
end
```

Calling the method:

```
authenticated?(false)
authenticated?('whatever', 'cool')
```

You could also check the types of the arguments or use parameter ordering (for example `authenticated?(nil, nil, true)` where the first two arguments are the attribute and token, and the third argument is remember_token).

## method overloading via keyword arguments (Ruby 2.0+)

Keyword arguments are under-used in Ruby but they have been available since Ruby 2.0.

```
def authenticated?(remember_token: nil, attribute: nil, token: nil)
  if remember_token
    return false if remember_digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  elsif attribute && token
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end
end
```

Calling the method:

```
authenticated?(attribute: 'whatever', token: 'cool')
authenticated?(remember_token: false)
```

## method overloading via options hash (Ruby 1.9)

Very common pattern/idiom in Ruby to use an options hash:

```
def authenticated?(options = {})
  if options['remember_token']
    return false if options['remember_token'].nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  elsif options['attribute'] && options['token']
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end
end
```

Calling the method:

```
authenticated?(:attribute => 'whatever', :token => 'cool')
authenticated?(:remember_token => false)
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response! This will be great for future projects. In this case, I realized that the duplicate authenticated? method was actually a mistake. I removed one and changed the method call and all is well now.